# Any disadvantages of setting minsdkversion to a very low version in Android?

Tags: android

For each new Android Project created, a minsdkversion needs to be set for the project. I understand that minsdkversion is the lowest API level required for the app to run with. That said, why can't we just set minsdkversion to the lowest, which is 1, in every project? That way, the application can run on every device.

Answer (score 0):

When using Android Studio, if you try to use an API that was introduced in a SDK with a version greater than the minSdkVersion, you'll get a warning. If you ignore that and run it on an older device, your application will crash.

So setting a minSdkVersion defines on which devices your application is allowed to run. That way, you can safely use APIs that were defined on that version or any previous one (usual caveats apply regarding deprecation, removal, etc.).

You could still check for the version of the sdk before making the call to the newer API. That way you'll allow for older devices to work. However, you also need to implement the `else` path, and that might be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the minsdkversion to the lowest, you won't be able to use many of the cool, or maybe even crucial features that were introduced in the newer version of the SDK, for example, you can't use [ViewAnimationUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils#createCircularReveal(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float)) below sdk 21.

Of course you can always check for the sdk in your code, and run only if the feature is supported, but you'll end up quickly with a boatload of `if` statements, and the development and maintenance of your code would be a nightmare or even impossible, plus, there wouldn't be much of an advantage to it, as the majority of android devices currently run newer versions of the system, so you might be satisfied with targeting 90% of the phone market or even lower, depending on your needs.

Comment: I understand that some features are not provided in low API level, but what if the targetsdkversion is set to a very high level, then that will not enable advanced features. Is that correct?

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` is the version of sdk you're specifically targeting, actually, it's advisable to set it as high as possible to use the latest features